# Backup files from a server to another

Tags: backup, server, provider

is it possible to create backup saving some files (copy and replace) from a server to another, not necessary the same provider  ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync setup through cron is the canonical  way of doing this

Comment: Nice, thanks ! 
Is the only way to do this, server commands ? Not possible with PHP scripts ?

Comment: I'll try to use easyXDM library, I prefer to implement that with javascript or php.